# Execution failed for task ':hardware_buttons:compileDebugKotlin' > Compilation Error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
Execution failed for task ':hardware_buttons:compileDebugKotlin'. > Compilation error. See log for more details

e: D:\Flutter_Software\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\hardware_buttons-1.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\flutter\moum\hardware_buttons\EmptyActivityLifecycleCallbacks.kt: (8, 6): Class 'EmptyActivityLifecycleCallbacks' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onActivityPaused(@NonNull p0: Activity): Unit defined in android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks

e: D:\Flutter_Software\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\hardware_buttons-1.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\flutter\moum\hardware_buttons\EmptyActivityLifecycleCallbacks.kt: (9, 5): 'onActivityPaused' overrides nothing
e: D:\Flutter_Software\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\hardware_buttons-1.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\flutter\moum\hardware_buttons\EmptyActivityLifecycleCallbacks.kt: (11, 5): 'onActivityResumed' overrides nothing


e: D:\Flutter_Software\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\hardware_buttons-1.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\flutter\moum\hardware_buttons\HardwareButtonsWatcherManager.kt: (74, 42): Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun onActivityStarted(@NonNull p0: Activity): Unit defined in flutter.moum.hardware_buttons.EmptyActivityLifecycleCallbacks

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Exception: Gradle task assemble Debug failed with exit code 1
```

this is the error message i get every time I try to run my app, I wouldn't understand what exactly is the problem is. Even though I have created only java application.

Even I tried finding it in stack overflow earlier but that didn't helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of this package `hardware_buttons`. Either remove it or use a compatible version